# Sqoop - getting java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to connect to Oracle DB Server

Tags: sqoop

Using Sqoop, I am trying to connect to Oracle DB and then list the databases available. 
But when I try to execute the command, I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Please find the command and the exception that I get as mentioned below:

```
[hadoop@njpas01 bin]$ ./sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@DEVDB1:1521 --username dev_user -P
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

15/04/01 14:56:24 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5
Enter password:
15/04/01 14:56:35 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
15/04/01 14:56:35 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
15/04/01 14:56:35 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.listDatabases(OracleManager.java:695)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

There is **no firewall issue**. The port 1521 is accessible from the machine where I run the Sqoop command.
**Oracle Version - 11g** Enterprise edition.
**ojdbc6.jar** Oracle connector is placed in the Sqoop lib folder.

Please let me know what is the cause of this issue. I have done a similar operation with SQL Server and successfully listed the data base, imported the data from DB to HDFS. But I am facing this issue in Oracle DB. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I made some more analysis on this and found that the **list-tables** command will work for the same Sqoop command as mentioned below.                                                                                                    sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@DEVDB1:1521 --username dev_user -P

Comment: Could you file a bug with the community? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP/.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error when trying to connect to oracle database using sqoop command.

in the sqoop statement , used the hostname which is not reachable from the node where sqoop command is executed. try the below command to check if your host of oracle is reachable:

ping hostname

if you get ping:Unknown host, then sqoop won't connect to oracle server.

So request use IPaddress in the sqoop statement and make sure that below command succeeded (got response)

ping IPaddress;

PING 10.xx.xx.xx (10.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.xx.xx.xx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.39 ms

After updating the ipadress, i was able to connect to oracle database.

sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.xx.xxx.xx:1521/dbname--username ur_username --password ur_password

Comment: Blind shot into the dark. The OP clearly states: *There is no firewall issue. The port 1521 is accessible from the machine where I run the Sqoop command.* So connectivity can't be the problem.