# sqoop data from oracle to hive ERROR

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to sqoop data from oracle to HDFS. I'm using sqoop for this purpose.
I downloaded `ojdbc6.jar` and put it in `/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/sqoop/lib` path and executed the following command to check whether i'm able to connect to oracle database.

```
    sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service --username XXXX --password XXXX --verbose;
```

i'm getting the following error.

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
15/05/29 15:24:42 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5.2.2.0.0-2041
15/05/29 15:24:42 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
15/05/29 15:24:42 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/05/29 15:24:43 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
15/05/29 15:24:43 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
15/05/29 15:24:43 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
15/05/29 15:24:44 DEBUG oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop can be called by Sqoop!
15/05/29 15:24:44 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
15/05/29 15:24:44 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
15/05/29 15:24:44 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname
15/05/29 15:24:45 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Instantiated new connection cache.
15/05/29 15:24:45 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
15/05/29 15:24:45 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager@2f37e8bc
15/05/29 15:24:46 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Creating a new connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service, using username: username
15/05/29 15:24:46 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
15/05/29 15:25:07 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.listDatabases(OracleManager.java:695)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Is this error because of grant permissions? do i need t grant any permissions? or this is an connection error?

Comment: can u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418270/sqoop-getting-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-connect-to-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the sqoop command and found this solution. it worked for me.
I pinged the hostname from cmd and found out the ip address it is pinging to.
I replaced the hostname with the ipaddress in the sqooop execution command and it is working.